# How to make git project as Android Project?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

[image]

I receive projects from github.

They are android project. But they does not have android.jar, project.properties, ...

How can I use them as Android Project?

Comment: You can just copy and paste .project file from another project, open it, rename the `<name>YourProjectNameHere</name>` and you should be able to import the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an android-maven project.

I think there are two ways:

**First**

You'll need to download [MAVEN](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi) and [Install](http://maven.apache.org/download.cgi#Installation) it.

Once completed, go to the command line. Check that maven is working by typing..

```
mvn --version
```

Once you get it working, with the command line, navigate to the project directory (where the pom.xml file is located) and type..

```
mvn clean install
```

This should generate the necessary files.

**Second**

Download the [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) (Maven to Eclipse) eclipse plugin.
Once installed, go to:

File -> Import -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects -> Choose the project folder

If you're using **Android Studio**, there is also an option available to import maven projects.
Personally, I prefer the first method... but it's up to you :)

Comment: Thanks, It was maven! I have been heard.

Answer (score 0):

2 options:

1. Ask them to Create a new project from existing source.
2. Push your .project file to github, and eclipse should be able to setup the android project correctly.